# If else statement query, Validator

Tags: c#, validation

I have an insert client form which allows my administrator to insert clients into the database table.

My client table contains the following column:
1) c_id
2) c_name
3) c_address
4) c_contactinfo
5) c_refno
6) c_profileinfo
7)  staff_id

I have another table called the staff table.
In the staff table, the database contains the following columns:
1) u_id
2) username
3) u_password
4) role

*Note, staff id and u_id are the same thing.

What i'm trying to do is, to create some sort of validation for my textBox_staffid.Text so that it will only allow staff id numbers which exist in the database.
For instance, if the staff id is up till 5 only, the user cannot enter 6 as the staff id.

Please help!

Comment: Is there actually a question here? What have you tried? What exactly are you stuck with?

Comment: Considered using if else but it seems complicated :S

Comment: What is too complicated about it? Perhaps you ought to show us the code you've tried and why you dislike it.

Comment: @SamuelLee i am not sure but if i am not wrong you want to check value of textBox_staffid in staff table and if it is exist then insert into client table

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a ComboBox, so you don't need to validate?

1. Retrieve `List<Staff>`
2. Bind `ComboBox` `ItemsSource` to your retrieved `List<Staff>`
3. Bind `DisplayMemberPath`, `SelectedValuePath`, and `SelectedValue`

That way you will only be able to select the existing Staff IDs.

And to be exciting, you can make it a `Dictionary<T1, T2> StaffMembers` property to bind your `ComboBox` `ItemsSource` to.

For WPF:

XAML:

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource={Binding StaffMembers} SelectedValuePath="Key" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
```

Code-behind:

```
 List<Staff> staffList = dbContext.Staff.ToList().Distinct();
 foreach(Staff s in staffList) {
      StaffMembers.Add(s.u_id, s.u.username);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try attaching to the [Leave](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event for the textbox and in there query the database (or a cache of the table you have made) to see if the value in the textbox is in the staff table.  If it's not present in the table you can refocus on the staffid textbox so that they have to enter a valid ID.